# Skewed data with many zeros: Simple and multiple regression

Tags: regression, stata

I read some research papers about Lachenbruch methods- 2 parts model. I am a clinician cum researcher and don't have much knowledge/experience in statistics.

We used a scale (St. George's Respiratory Questionnaire) in a study (in general village population in India), 0 indicates no problem and 100 indicates severity. The dataset has a large number of zeros (indicates no problem), and is positively skewed. We have to do simple and multiple regression analyses to determine the associated factors. We use Stata, but we are not experts. Could you please let us know the process of analysing this data? Could you please help us with the Stata commands?

Comment: This is a difficult question for this forum. Questions focused on how to use software are off-topic here, but this one would not go down well on Stack Overflow either as it is too open-ended. (I monitor all questions on Stata there.) Questions about specific statistical issues are welcome here, but there are too many things in which you are interested (two part models, bounded variables, skewness, regression) to allow an answer with reasonable scope. I'd recommend study of the advice in the Help center and more searching of the site before coming back with a specific question.